# Django and jQuery.formset, how to manipulate delete button position

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates, formset

I'm trying to set my formset in django, using the famous jQuery plugin

[jQuery.formset.js](https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset/blob/master/src/jquery.formset.js)

All works perfectly, but I have some problem to set the right position of the delete button.

Now it is set in the last column of my table, like in the following figure:

[image: Actual formset table layout]

But my aim is to replace the delete button in the same line of the the **add button (+)**.

I have found in the code the following instructions, but I don't now how could set it for my aim:

```
  var delButtonHTML = '<a class="' + options.deleteCssClass + '" href="javascript:void(0)">' + options.deleteText +'</a>';
                if (options.deleteContainerClass) {
                    // If we have a specific container for the remove button,
                    // place it as the last child of that container:
                    row.find('[class*="' + options.deleteContainerClass + '"]').append(delButtonHTML);
                } else if (row.is('TR')) {
                    // If the forms are laid out in table rows, insert
                    // the remove button into the last table cell:
                    row.children(':last').append(deleteButtonHTML);
                } else if (row.is('UL') || row.is('OL')) {
                    // If they're laid out as an ordered/unordered list,
                    // insert an <li> after the last list item:
                    row.append('<li>' + deleteButtonHTML + '</li>');
                } else {
                    // Otherwise, just insert the remove button as the
                    // last child element of the form's container:
                    row.append(delButtonHTML);
                }
```

How could I get this instruction to achive my aim?

Answer (score 0):

add container class with same class:

```
deleteContainerClass: 'hapus',
addContainerClass: 'hapus',
```